# Danger of reverse proxying with nginx 80 and 443 to a node process listening on port 3000?

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have an unusual situation. I made a node app listening on port 3000 which I reverse proxy from 443, and if I get a request on port 80, I revert to 443. Everything works well online, but this application is designed to run offline on its own server as a turnkey system. Online it makes sense to be on 443, but offline, when the server is not connected to the internet, it only needs to be online for iOS client devices, which only are allowed to connect on 443 (due to Apple Transport Layer, thanks Apple). Otherwise, it really doesn't matter to the system whether it's on 80 or 443.

Now, the interesting part. On Windows, when the server is offline and a client connects to the server over https, I get a warning about Windows not being able to check the certificate revocation list, clearly because the server is not online and can't connect to a certificate authority. The warning does not go away if I install the certificate, and it screws up the system since it can never check any revocation list while it's offline (as it's meant to operate). If the device had connected to the internet, it could verify the certificate has not been revoked, but it is an extra step for a client computer to be on the internet to have an authority do the revocation step. My clients are fairly tech-non-saavy, so it's hard to explain this requirement when they simply want to connect.

I think I found a partial solution -- have nginx listen and reverse proxy both 443 and 80 to port 3000 (duplicate the server block, just provide keys on the 443 listening). In that way, I can tell customers who don't want to do the online check before connecting to connect on port 80, and I can tell iOS customers to connect on port 443.

I just don't know if I am doing something dangerous listening on both ports and directing them both to 3000. The system seems to work fine, but I don't know enough about this setup to know if I'm walking into a problem. I'd appreciate any suggestions about whether this is good or bad. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely fine.

And you don't need to duplicate the server blocks completely, you can have both 80 and 443 listeners on the same block, so they share the rest of the server config.  The only difference is the 443 listener terminates SSL at that point.

Something like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  foo.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/pki/tls/certs/foo.example.com.bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/foo.example.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
```